# How to declare global variables used by all the kernel code in kernel area?

Tags: c, kernel, system-calls

I'm learning how to create custom system call and going to implement the code(save.c) that takes the ptr char pointer as argument and then copy the string pointed by `ptr` into `sys_mybuf`. implement the code(load.c) that takes `ptr` char pointer as argument and then copy the string in `sys_mybuf` into the buffer pointed by `ptr`. So, I expected the following codes. But It seems not to work. I want char array to be used by all the kernel system call code. What should I do?

save.c

```
  1 #include <linux/kernel.h>
  2 #define STRING__SIZE 501
  3 char sys_mybuf[STRING__SIZE]; // a string of at most size 500.
  4 asmlinkage int sys_save(char* ptr)
  5 {
  6     int index = 0;

 17 
 18     ptr[index] = '\0';
 19     return index; // the number of bytes actually read.
 20 }
```

load.c

```
  1 #include <linux/kernel.h>
  2 // extern
  3 asmlinkage int sys_load(char* ptr)

 17     ptr[index] = '\0';
 18     return index;
 19 }
```

~

Comment: *How* does it not work? And are you really not making an external declaration of the variable in e.g. `load.c`?

Comment: `gcc` tells me that `sys_mybuf` is undeclared in load.c

Comment: Is [this](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/2010/11/declaring-global-variables-in-linux-kernel/) good solution for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I guessed in my comment. The problem is simply that you don't *declare* the variable in the file `load.c`.

For a quick solution, add these following lines to `load.c`:

```
#define STRING__SIZE 501
extern char sys_mybuf[STRING__SIZE];
```

This tells the compiler that `sys_mybuf` is a global variable declared in another translation unit (e.g. source file).

What you *really* should do, is put this in a header file, and include that header file by all files that needs to access the global data.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, but it might cause you some troubles : `sys_mybuf[STRING__SIZE] = '\0';`, here `STRING__SIZE` is outside the buffer.

Comment: @NoWiS Didn't look that far into the code, but yes that is a of-by-one error that will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I have another question. we can say `sys_mybuf` is in kernel area?

Comment: @inherithandle Yes it's in kernel space. User-space applications will not be able to access it.